# What is the "-d" in "npm -d install"?

Tags: npm

I've seen some posts that refer to running `npm` with a `-d` argument. For example, [this issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/pull/73) refers to doing `npm -d install coffee-script`. There are [a few other pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22npm%20-d%20install%22) that also refer to this syntax, including the [install instructions](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare-Dashboard/wiki) for at least one npm package.

But I've been unable to find any documentation for this `-d` argument. The [docs for `npm install`](http://npmjs.org/doc/install.html) make no mention of `-d`, nor does [the npm FAQ](http://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html), nor do any of the other documentation pages I've looked through.

Does the `-d` option do anything? If so, what?

Comment: I think that should be 
"npm i -D .........."
which would be equivalent of
"npm install --save-dev ............"

Comment: @DevWL, did you read the other answers to this question? :-) `-d` and `-D` are different. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463702/87399

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It's a shortcut for `--loglevel info`

See the [*Shorthands and Other CLI Niceties* section](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties):

> - `-d`: `--loglevel info`

Comment: Ah... of *course* the command-line parameters wouldn't be documented on the pages that talk about command-line parameters or the commands they apply to. Silly me!

Comment: @JoeWhite Ugh, was just tearing my hair out trying to figure out what it is. Google isn't exactly friendly to short command line options.

Comment: Makes much more sense to be under "misc"... Just ask Google if they agree: http://www.google.com/search?q=npm+install+-d

Comment: What was `debug` then again? Ahh, turns out there is no `--loglevel debug` but "verbose" (`-dd`) and "silly" (`-ddd`). Fair enough.