# what does npm install -d --save mean

Tags: node.js, npm

I have recently come across one of these statements in a node project that I am currently working on that we use to install node modules locally

```
npm install -d --save
```

Can somebody please tell me what it means as earlier we used to use simply npm install

I want to know the difference between the two

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783230/what-is-the-d-in-npm-d-install

Comment: Also, there's always the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html).

Comment: i tried googling didn't exactly find it..anyways thanks guys and jibsales can u please post your answer as an actual answer so that i can close this question :)

Comment: @jibsales dude can you please post your comment as an answer so that I can close this question

Comment: @ajp15243 If only that were true!  The documentation is now missing.

Comment: Docs page has changed: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html:

> The following shorthands are parsed on the command-line:
>   -d: --loglevel info

From https://www.npmjs.org/doc/install.html

> --save: Package will appear in your dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

It adds it to your dependencies in your packages.json

For example, I just did

> npm install async --save

It added this to my packages.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "async": "~0.2.10",
```

Before you do that however, make sure you create your packages.json by running

```
npm init
```

By adding packages to source control (but not the node_modules it lays down locally), when others consume your solution, when they do 'npm install' after pulling your solution, it will pull those dependencies - you don't have to distribute.

https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html