# What does npm -D flag mean?

Tags: npm

I am about to install [this npm package](https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config) and it says `npm install -D load-grunt-config`. What does the `-D` flag do?

Comment: Sorry for duplicate question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783230/what-is-the-d-in-npm-d-install has answer, however the comments are much more inline, I guess because they were made by developers that knew the answer and had been through the same.

Comment: you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60538593/8134164

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the "-d" in "npm -d install"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783230/what-is-the-d-in-npm-d-install)

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake `-D` is different from `-d`.

Comment: @thdoan yes they are different

Answer (score 317, accepted):

The `-D` flag is the shortcut for: `--save-dev`. Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

> **-D, --save-dev**: Package will appear in your **devDependencies**.

Comment: So, what does it do?

Comment: @kevin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223051/grunt-js-what-does-save-dev-mean-in-npm-install-grunt-save-dev

Comment: For me, the -D flag will not update package.json, forcing me to use --save-dev instead. Crazy as usual :(

Comment: @Kevin That's another topic isn't it?

Comment: @Hiro, OP wrote "what does the -D flag do?"

Answer (score 39):

As described in the [NPM Install Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> -D, `--save-dev`: Package will appear in your `devDependencies.`

Which means that the package will **not** be installed if you do `npm install --production`.

A detailed explanation of the different types of dependencies: [SO-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/4508555)

Comment: Adding to this, the equivalent using yarn is `yarn add <package...> [--dev/-D]`