# Error: Module `@nuxtjs/vuetify` not found. (v2.0.0-beta.2)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Because of fibers error on cPanel/CentOS/Cloudlinux servers, I'm using `v2.0.0-beta.2` of `@nuxtjs/vuetify` in my Nuxt app.

But npm returns error on build or dev running.

No problem with v1.11.2, but the `alpha` and `beta` versions have error.

```
✖ Nuxt Fatal Error
Error: Module `@nuxtjs/vuetify` not found. Please ensure `@nuxtjs/vuetify` is in `devDependencies` and
installed. HINT: During build step, for npm/yarn, `NODE_ENV=production` or `--production` should NOT be
used.
```

[image: 2020-06-04_163704]

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^2.0.0-beta.2"
}
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
]
```

Comment: Did you find the vuetify folder in node_modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the `node_modules` folder and re-runned the `npm install` and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the bellow commands

1. Delete node_modules
2. run `npm i` if you have previously npm installed on you machine otherwise run `npm install` then run `npm i` .
3. run `npm run build`
4. run `npm run start`

Answer (score 0):

I tried Fred solution but didn't work out for me.

However I run this command `npm install @nuxtjs/vuetify -D` to install the vuetify component and the problem solved.

Comment: Adding , It is shortcut for `--save-dev`. for more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177336/what-does-npm-d-flag-mean)