# what does -D mean in npm install -D tailwindcss?

Tags: tailwind-css, logfile

Installing TailWindCSS, the command in npm `install -D tailwindcss`, what does log-level info denotes?
NPM- node package manager,
D-log level info

I was trying to learn Tailwindcss and then encountered the command for installing the package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does npm -D flag mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177336/what-does-npm-d-flag-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-D` means that tailwind will be installed as a development dependency, so it will only be installed in development environments. It is the shorthand for [`--save-dev`](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file).